# When to use *it instead of it for iterating over a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, auto

I have found myself confused about when to use ***it** instead of **it** for iterating over an std::vector. Is there any rule (or easy way to remember) that I can have in mind so as not to confuse those two ways of iterating over stl collections?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::vector<int> x;
    x.push_back(3);
    x.push_back(5);

    for(auto it : x){
        std::cout<<it<<std::endl; // Why to use it here and not *it?
    }
    for( auto it= x.begin(); it!=x.end(); ++it){
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl; // Why to use *it here and not it?
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `*it` whenever `it` is an iterator that needs to be de-referenced. As in the second loop.

Comment: `for(auto it : x)` already iterates over values, no iterator is involved.

Comment: Strange question, if the first variant type of it is int, how can you use `*` for int? The second is iterator.  May be you should not use "auto" at all, if you not undertand which type is auto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range based `for` loops loop on *elements*:

```
for(auto e : x) {
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

Iterators returned by `begin` and `end` are... well... *iterators*.
You have to dereference them to get an element:

```
for( auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `it` is an iterator, `*it` gives the value that iterator corresponds to. Even better, just use a *range-for* loop:

```
for (auto& element : vector) {
    // `element` is the value inside the vector
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the two ways of iterating like this:

```
for (auto it = begin(list) ; it != end(list) ; it++) {
    auto element = *it;
    // do stuff with element
}

for (auto element : list) {
    // do stuff with element
}
```

See the second way as a shorthand of the first way.